# How Adobe Flash AEC works? + AEC partially working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, aec

I'm trying to build a simple red5-flash application, where two people can converse with each other. I have two flash players for persons A and B, each with a publisher part (that takes the live webcam feed and sends it to a red5 server, that is recorded and published) and a viewer part (that fetches the opposite person's stream from red5 and plays it).

**Problem:** I'm using Adobe's Acoustic Echo Cancellation through getEnhancedMicrophone. It causes a significant improvement and reduces echoes, A and B have an echo-less talk - that's good - but when I play back the recorded version on the server machine, the echoes remain there.

**Question 1:** How is that possible? Any possible solutions?

**Question 2:** How does Adobe AEC actually work?
Does it use some comparison method to filter feedback into the mic (fading out the audio that went out the audio output, and is going in through the input again)?
OR
Does it compare inputs like so - 2 sends something to 1, feedback occurs and 1 sends the "echo" to 2 (of course making way through red5 and hence getting recorded) - 2 receives the echo and filters it by comparing it with what it sent earlier and so on?

Comment: I don't have experience with AEC but from the sounds of it the server is just applying a filter to the stream when it sends it.

Comment: AEC works real-time, on the client side. I think Flash basically reduces (kills rogue frames?) feedback from Aout to Ain (A = audio).

Comment: I really doubt it is client side as I have never seen any filter objects for the sound classes.